# Erro "No module named 'pytube'"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ao instalar um pacote utilizando o PIP não consigo utilizá-lo. Exemplo:

```
pip install pytube
```

Até aí tudo bem, baixa sem problemas#

No IDLE:

```
import pytube
```

Resultado:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pytube
ImportError: No module named 'pytube'
```

Comment: Experimenta correr o teu programa com python2, `python FILE.py`. Ou tenta instalar `pip3 install pytube`

Comment: Está funcionando, agora. Com o IDLE 3.6

Comment: digita "sudo pip install pytube", se você estiver usando o Ubuntu!

Comment: Acho a opção acima mais provável também. Se você já tinha o Python 2 instalado e depois instalou o 3, você tem que ter certeza que está rodando o seu script com a mesma versão a que o `pip` se refere. `python  script.py` + `pip` ou `python3 script.py` + `pip3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o problema seja causado pela existência de múltiplas versões do pip e do python instaladas na máquina.

Vá ao terminal e digite:

```
pip --version
```

O retorno deverá ser similar a:

```
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

Note que, no final do retorno, entre parênteses, indica a versão do python. Que no meu caso é a 3.5. Assim, ao utilizar o comando pip eu estarei instalando o pacote no python3.5

Você pode utilizar um comando similar para saber para qual versão do python o comando *python* aponta:

```
python --version
```

No meu caso, a resposta é:

```
Python 2.7.11
```

Já para o python3:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.1
```

Assim, se eu instalar algo com o pip, eu devo executar com o comando *python3*, que corresponde a versão do pip.

Você pode fazer o mesmo com os comandos *pip2, pip3, python2, python3*... O que você deve encontrar são as versões compatíveis do pip com o python. O autocomplete do terminal pode te ajudar bastante nessa tarefa(digite python e aperte tab varias vezes para ver todos os disponíveis, o mesmo para o pip).